# git deploy subfolder of repository

Tags: git

I have a local git repo i use to backup 2 folders: site (my actual website) and files (psd files and such) and i push them to a remote on a networkdrive.

Now to get the site online i used to just upload them using ftp but i would like to just use git for this. I've set this up using this instructions http://blog.wekeroad.com/2009/11/23/deploying-a-web-application-with-git-and-ftp

But of course if i just do git clone i get my 2 folders, site and files. Obviously i just want the contents of the folder 'site'.

So, is there a way to do this?
Or is there a better work flow to do this?

Comment: i now have created to submodules for my 2 folders, and a remote for the whole project. The question remains now how do i clone just one of the submodules from the remote, or do i have to create a remote for each of the submodules?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at subtree merges. This way you can use one repo to push everything you need via ftp.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i was reading about subtree and submodules, isn't submodules a better fit here?

Comment: no due to the fact that submodules may not get included when you ftp upload. but I may be wrong. this is the last I heard about it.

Answer (score 0):

Tell Git to ignore your `files` folder in `.gitingore` like this:

```
files/
```